# What does the path '/../' mean?

Tags: filesystems, path

Wondering where a path that looks like this *'/../'*  would point to outside a file? I'm guessing it might be something like always specifying the *root* directory and then the relative parent directory to the file it was written in?

Comment: The parent of root is root so it's the same as /

Comment: So do you mean writing /../ is the same as / then...?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can't go to root's parent so it is directed to root itself

Comment: However, see [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12283/80216).

Comment: `/../` is only meaningful if it is *within* a path.

Comment: yes I've realised this in the context of the codebase I was in - it was pointing to a path outside it as an absolute path

Comment: Did you see this in somebody's code?  Someone might prepend this to an arbitrary string (e.g. a command line parameter) to force it to be an absolute path (and also avoid the 'implementation-defined behavior'  allowed by the POSIX standard described in @G-Man's link).

Comment: It's likely an attempt by a malicious actor to circumvent a restriction - you used to see `/../` in URLs, hoping that the web server would translate that directly into a path from the server's data directory.  It's certainly something to watch out for if your programs ever access files on behalf of less-trusted users.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Lets break `/../` down piece by piece

The first (leftmost) `/`indicates the root of the file system.
This is the topmost level of the filesystem.

`..` means the parent folder
However, since we are at the topmost level, we cannot go higher, so we are still at the topmost folder.

adding `/` at the end indicates a folder.  This is never mandatory, unless specifying a subfolder path or file.  So we are still at the topmost folder on the file system.

So, `/../` is no different than typing `/`

Comment: Except when you're in chroot, and the kernel is sufficiently buggy that such tricks let you escape the chroot. (It used to be the case years ago, I think.)

Comment: The trailing slash can be significant in some cases. For example, if `/example` is a symlink to a directory, `ls -l /example` will display the symlink, whereas `ls -l /example/` will display the contents of the directory.

Comment: you could contrast with   `cd ../abc`   i.e. where `../` does make a difference.   I guess it's only useful for relative paths, not for absolute paths.

Comment: @barlop `../` can have an effect for absolute paths: `/foo/bar/../quux` = `/foo/quux`. Some more useful examples: 1) realizing you just tab completed a really long directory name, but it wasn't the one you wanted. `../` might be quicker than backspacing 50 times. 2) `foo=/long/absolute/path/to/foo; bar=$foo/../bar;`

Comment: @TobySpeight I believe that to be the case, yes, as this is mostly Windows-land

Comment: @grawity Closing the `..` escape path if implementing `chroot` as a jail is as obvious as closing the barn door to keep the animals in; you don't miss a case like that: the most obvious escape path. That leads me to suspect that early `chroot` implementations might not have had inescapability as a *requirement*.

Comment: @Kaz I think it was even explicitly stated that they didn't. I can't remember where, but there was a description about how chroot was originally nothing more than a helper for buildsystems.